# Class object distinction

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a Space Ship Simulator project and I came across a problem. In my code I have an `Arrow` class and I create 4 arrow objects that are going to be buttons.

This is my code:

```
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

SCR_WIDTH = 700
SCR_HEIGHT = 900

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Ship Simulator")

# image loads
bg_image = pygame.image.load("img/space_background.jpg")
bg_image = pygame.transform.scale(bg_image, (SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT))
ss_board = pygame.image.load("img/spaceship_board.png")


class Arrow:
    def __init__(self, degree, x, y):
        self.degree = degree
        self.active = 0
        self.arrow_list = []
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.active = 0
        self.released = True
        # arrow color: R: 0, G: 234, B: 0
        for x in range(2):
            img = pygame.image.load(f"img/arrow_{x}.png")
            self.arrow_list.append(img)

        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.arrow_list[self.active], self.degree)
        self.width = self.image.get_width()
        self.height = self.image.get_height()
        self.rect = Rect((self.x, self.y), (self.width, self.height))

    def draw(self):
        # get mouse position
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # check mouseover and clicked conditions
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.active == 0 and self.released:
                self.active = 1
                self.released = False
                print('Active')

            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
                self.released = True

            if self.active and self.released:
                if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
                    self.active = 0
                    print('Inactive')
                    self.released = False

        # draw arrow on screen
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.arrow_list[self.active], self.degree)
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


arrowRight = Arrow(0, 553, 700)
arrowLeft = Arrow(180, 425, 700)
arrowUp = Arrow(91, 440, 776)
arrowDown = Arrow(271, 557, 779)

run = True
while run:
    # background
    screen.blit(bg_image, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(ss_board, (0, 200))

    # draw arrows
    arrowRight.draw()
    arrowLeft.draw()
    arrowUp.draw()
    arrowDown.draw()

    # event handlers
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # quit game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

I have two requirements for the buttons:

1. If I click a button that is active, it should be deactivated again. I already managed to implement this.
2. If I click a button that is not active, it should be activated, and *every other active button should be deactivated*.

How can I implement the second requirement? Right now, it is possible for all four buttons to be active at the same time.

Comment: This isn't even really a Pygame question; the same *logical* problem could be demonstrated with instances of any class that has an "activated" concept, even without drawing anything on the screen. Please read [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link the buttons. Create a list of the buttons and set the list of buttons to each button object:

```py
class Arrow:
    def __init__(self, degree, x, y):
        self.linkedButtons = []
        self.active = 0
        # [...]
```

```py
arrowList = [
    Arrow(0, 553, 700)
    Arrow(180, 425, 700)
    Arrow(91, 440, 776)
    Arrow(271, 557, 779)
]
for arrow in arrowList:
    arrow.linkedButtons = arrowList
```

Deactivate all buttons before you activate a button:

```py
class Arrow:
    # [...]

    def draw(self):
        # get mouse position
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # check mouseover and clicked conditions
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.active == 0 and self.released:
                
                # deactivate all buttons 
                for button in self.linkedButtons: 
                    button.active = 0                

                # activate this button
                self.active = 1
                self.released = False
                print('Active')
   
            # [...]
```

Draw the buttons in a loop:

```py
run = True
while run:
    # background
    screen.blit(bg_image, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(ss_board, (0, 200))

    # draw arrows
    for arrow in arrowList:
        arrow.draw()

    # event handlers
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # quit game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I'd make the "list of buttons" an attribute on a ControlPanel object instead, and have the buttons reference their containing ControlPanel instance. That way you don't have to update the individual buttons to reference each other.  (I think having buttons directly referencing and deactivating each other is a violation of OOP, but YMMV.) Include a `<ControlPanel>.add_button()` so it knows about each of them. Then call `<ControlPanel>.deactivate_all_buttons()` from within `<Arrow>.draw()`.

Comment: @SarahMesser This can be the next step. But you'd rather not rewrite all the code at once. Make it run with minimal changes first before refactoring it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should make a list of array button like

```
arrow_list = [arrowRight,arrowLeft,arrowUp,arrowDown]
```

then in the game loop you can can function to do the rest of the work

```
def button_activation(arrow_list):
    index = none
    for i,arrow in enumerate(arrow_list):
        if arrow.activate:
           index = i
    for i,arrow in enumerate(arrow_list):
        if index != i:
            arrow.activate = False
```